# Use expression as filter argument in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to search the local filesystem for files matching a glob pattern, and get the path relative to a parent directory. Following is the code

```
- name: check for local configuration files
  debug:
    var: 
     - "{{ item | relpath('{{ playbook_dir }}/templates/httpd/{{ vhost.user }}') }}"
  with_fileglob: "{{ playbook_dir }}/templates/httpd/{{ vhost.user }}/*.j2"
```

The above code is not working since Ansible is unable to resolve the nested expression?

I am planning to pre-evaluate the expression into a variable using `set_fact` and pass it to `relpath`.

Is it possible to achieve the result without this extra variable declaration? Is it possible to use an expression as argument to a filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access variables by name inside jinja expressions:

```
"{{ item | relpath(playbook_dir+'/templates/httpd/'+vhost.user) }}"
```